# how to delete the elements that have the same prefix String (2 to 5 Chars) in a List?

Tags: scala

there is a List as below:

```
val a: List[String] = List(aaaaa1, aaaaa2, bb, cc, dd1, ee, dd2, dd3, ff, ggg1, ggg2, aaaaa3)
```

how to delete the elements that have the same prefix String (2 to 5 Chars) in a List?

for example:

"aaaaa1","aaaaa2","aaaaa3" have the same prefix String "aaaaa"(5 Chars). so delete them.

"dd1","dd2","dd3" have the same prefix String "dd"(2 Chars). so delete them.

"ggg1","ggg2" have the same prefix String "ggg"(3 Chars). so delete them.

expected:

```
val b: List[String] = List(bb,cc,ee,ff)
```

==========

thx for your idea. now fix it.

```
a.foldLeft(scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap[String,Int]().withDefaultValue(0)){
  case(m,e) =>
    val k = e.take(2)
    m(k)+=1
    m
}.filter(_._2==1).keys.toList
```

Comment: Just compare the 2 chars prefix ;) no need to compare 3, 4, 5 chars prefix since it will be included.  you will have to write a beautiful code that take fist element, take first 2 char of that element, filter the list with that (and remove from source element). If result is 1 element => it is in the result list.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
a.groupBy(_.take(2)).values.collect{case x if x.length == 1 => x.head}
// res0: Iterable[String] = List(cc, bb, ee, ff)
```

The original order is not retained because the collection passes through a `Map()` phase which, by definition, has no intrinsic order.

---

**update**

The original order can be preserved but it requires a two-step procedure.

```
val uniqPrefix = a.groupBy(_.take(2)).mapValues(_.length == 1)
a.filter(x => uniqPrefix(x.take(2)))
// res0: List[String] = List(bb, cc, ee, ff)
```

Comment: thx @jwvh by the way. is it difficult to retained the original order?

Answer (score 1):

I think this code can be used in this case:

```
val list = List(
"aaaaa1", "aaaaa2", "bb", "cc", "dd1", "ee", "dd2", "dd3", "ff", "ggg1", "ggg2", "aaaaa3")

val prefix2items = list.groupBy(_.take(2))

list.filter(item => prefix2items(item.take(2)).length == 1) 
//res0: List[String] = List(bb, cc, ee, ff)
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work even if you have multiple character in prefix

The prefix will be identify until get a digit, the character after digit will not consider as prefix here

val a = List("abb1","abbbbbb1","aaaaa2","aaaaa3","aaaaaa44")

"abb1" will be removed here

```
a.filter(_.takeWhile(data => !data.isDigit).groupBy(_.toChar).values.exists{case x if (2 to 5).contains(x.length) => true case _ => false})
```

Comment: thx. but the duplicate elements their prefix no intersection.